# $F(x)=\int_{-2}^{2} dy f(x,y)$ is an even function, is $G(x)=\int_{-2}^{2} dy [f(x,y)]^2$ even?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, even-and-odd-functions

I have a real valued function in two real variables $f(x,y)$ which is essentially a black box. The only thing I really know is that
$$
F(x)=\int_{-2}^{2} f(x,y) dy
$$
is even and that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x) dx=1
$$
Can I conclude that
$$
G(x)=\int_{-2}^{2} \left[f(x,y)\right]^2 dy
$$
is also even? I looked for a counterexample, but couldn't find one. I intuitively feel like this should be true, but am struggling to make that more rigorous. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question but after doing some more work I have found a counterexample.

$$f(x,y)=\Theta (x) \left(x y^2-\frac{4 x}{3}\right)$$

Where $\Theta(x)$ is the step function, then

$$
F(x)=\int_{-2}^2 \Theta (x) \left(x y^2-\frac{4 x}{3}\right) \, dy=0
$$

Is an even function, but

$$
G(x)=\int_{-2}^2 \left(\Theta (x) \left(x y^2-\frac{4 x}{3}\right)\right)^2 \, dy= \frac{256 x^2 \Theta (x)}{45}
$$

Is not. However I believe that if $f(x,y)=f(-x,\pm y)$ then $G(x)=G(-x)$. I'd be glad to hear if anyone can give more general conditions on $f(x,y)$.